# Debugging in eclipse . Extract variables to excel sheet

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

Am debugging my application using eclipse. I have a list which has 100 objects within it. I need to extract the values of those hundred objects in to an excel sheet **in debug-window** and i should compare. Is there anyway in eclipse I can do it while debugging ??

Right now, I wrote a program which will write in to an excel and am doing it which is very painful as I have to delete that code before moving it to production.

It would be good, if the debug plug-in itself has an option for this . can this be done ?

This will reduce our analysis timing

Comment: Why don' you print them to console?If possible :)

Comment: edited the question.. printing that means . adding print statements ; compile ; build and deploy. It involves all these process :( . when we have the values ready in debug mode and when we are able to see it in debug mode . am thinking why not we have an option to extract it ..

Comment: debug plug-in is not so intelligent

Comment: @Arun That is ok,Just a thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute code during `debug` in eclipse [Display View](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-display_view.htm)
Go to `Window -> Show View -> Display View`

You can write code to see the value of the expressions during debugging, you should be able to write code to extract values into excel.